# Make file available for download during input-step in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

During the the "input step", I need to make a binary file available for the user to download and validate.
Ideally as a clickable link directly in the input-step dialog if that is possible somehow?

"archive artifact" does not work, since the artifact only becomes visible after the job has finished.

A link directly to the file in workspace would be ideal, but there does not seem to exist a way for groovy to find out the URL to the workspace.

The html publisher might work. But the problem of linking to it from the input-step dialog remains.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to copy your file to $JENKINS_HOME/userContent and then access it via https://YourJenkinsHost.com/jenkins/userContent/YourFileName

Comment: I guess, but that could cause naming conflicts and race conditions between different jobs or runs of the same job if one is not careful.
And the problem of how to provide a clickable link in the input-step dialog remains.

Comment: You can add folders or even put a unique part to naming like timestamp of build number, but regarding input step I'm afraid that's not possible, unless you want to rewrite pipeline plugin.

Comment: That is my understanding too.
I believe I read somewhere that it is possible to customize the input using javascript somehow, but it seemed rather complicated.
Perhaps the html publisher is the best bet after all. At least it creates a clickable link. Just not in the most ideal place..